# how to change JTable Background Color default to white?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

I have a JTable that I am displaying in a JScrollpane. The JTable only
displays a few rows of information in its grid. The space below the 
grid to the bottom of the JPanel, 
that contains the JScrollpane, (Which in turn contains the JTable) is 
colored solid gray. 
I'd like to change that color to white. I tried setting the JTable's 
background color to 
white, [using the method setBackground(Color,WHITE) ] but that didn't 
work.

Can anyone tell me which method to use to change that gray to white?

Comment: Why do you want to change JTable Background Color default to white?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

depend of your code

- `JTable#setFillsViewportHeight(true);`

or

- `JScrollPane#getViewport().setBackground(JTable#getBackground());`

or you can to fits `JScrollPanes JViewport` to the `JTables view` by

- `JTable#setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(JTable#getPreferredSize());`

Comment: wincing on the last - that'll "work" only if the scrollPane is contained in a manager which lays out to prefSize. Anyway, setPrefScrollableViewportSize is just as bad as any of the setXXSize, simply don't

Comment: actually, in terms of usabilty the second is a no-go: it only appears like the table fills the entire scrollPane area, but doesn't - so behaviour expected from the table (f.i. componentPopups, tooltips, focus transfer by clicking) will not work and thus confuse the users

Comment: JTable#setFillsViewportHeight(true);  worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is to get the JViewport of the JScrollPane in your JTable and set its background color.

```
JTable table=new JTable(model);  
JScrollPane scroll=new JScrollPane(table);  
scroll.getViewport().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
```

Hope that gives a solution, for making your remaining table space as WHITE.

Comment: good idea - but not really recommended, see my comment in @mKorbel 's answer

Comment: @kleopatra: Well Said. Thanks for the Note. It lacks table behaviours, since the Table doesn't fill the entire scrollPane as it appears to be.